# extremum points

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, maximum, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to find Min and Max points of the polynomial below, but it seems that the expression is very complicated to mathematical, I've tried a numerical function, such as NMinimize, NRoots, Solve, Roots, Reduce, but I can't find something useful.
B and epsilon are some constant such that 10^6<B<12^6 and 0<epsilon<1.

```
    -((15 x^2 (30 - 22 B \[CurlyEpsilon]^2 + 23 \[CurlyEpsilon]^3))/(
     2 \[CurlyEpsilon]^4)) + (
     x^3 (72 - 52 B \[CurlyEpsilon]^2 + 54 \[CurlyEpsilon]^3))/(
     2 \[CurlyEpsilon]^5) + (
     2 (120 - 92 B \[CurlyEpsilon]^2 + 99 \[CurlyEpsilon]^3))/(
     x \[CurlyEpsilon]) + (
     x (520 - 388 B \[CurlyEpsilon]^2 + 
        409 \[CurlyEpsilon]^3))/\[CurlyEpsilon]^3 + (-1080 \
    \[CurlyEpsilon]^3 + 820 B \[CurlyEpsilon]^5 - 873 \ 
   [CurlyEpsilon]^6)/(
     2 \[CurlyEpsilon]^5) + (-62 \[CurlyEpsilon]^5 + 
      48 B \[CurlyEpsilon]^7 - 52 \[CurlyEpsilon]^8)/(
     2 x^2 \[CurlyEpsilon]^5)
```

Comment: `expr = (-1080 t^3 + 820 B t^5 - 873 t^6)/(
   2 t^5) + (-62 t^5 + 48 B t^7 - 52 t^8)/(2 t^5 x^2) + (
   2 (120 - 92 B t^2 + 99 t^3))/(
   t x) + ((520 - 388 B t^2 + 409 t^3) x)/t^3 - (
   15 (30 - 22 B t^2 + 23 t^3) x^2)/(
   2 t^4) + ((72 - 52 B t^2 + 54 t^3) x^3)/(2 t^5);
NMinimize[{expr, 10^6 < B < 12^6, 0 < t < 1}, {x, t, B}]`

Comment: your code does not return anything, but, i tried NMinimize and it does not give the correct values (you can try looking at the plot), I always need to decrease the ranges to get good numerical values, but I want a general solution with B and epsilon

Comment: The code from cvgmt returns: {-1.16517*10^8, {x -> 0.307182, t -> 0.999998, B -> 2.98598*10^6}}

Comment: thanks, he edited it, so now it works, but again, I need a general solution with B and epsilon